# How to find hash key where an array item is less than or equal to hash value in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and trying to solve [this question](http://www.ioi-jp.org/joi/2013/2014-yo/2014-yo-t2/2014-yo-t2.html) from IOI for my self-study.

I have the following hash and array. myhash has `popularity of sports => cost for construction`. Each `votes` value is the limit for construction. If it is less than or equal to popu_cost's cost for construction, it gets a vote and it will check from the highest popularity. Once it finds, no need to check other sports.

```
popu_cost = {1=>8, 2=>8, 3=>7, 4=>5, 5=>2, 6=>5, 7=>2, 8=>7, 9=>2, 10=>1}
votes = [2, 8, 4, 1, 8, 2, 10, 3, 2, 2]
```

Now I want to find hash key where `votes element <= hash value` and add to `results[]`.For example

```
votes[0], max cost afford is 2. So hash index 5 since 2 is less than or equal to 2
votes[1], 8 is hash index 1 since 8 is less than or equal to 8
votes[2], 4 is hash index 5 since 2 is less than or equal to 4
votes[3], 1 is hash index 10 since 1 is less than or equal to 1
votes[4], 8 is hash index 1 since 8 is less than or equal to 8
votes[5], 2 is hash index 5 since 2 is less than or equal to 2
votes[6], 10 is hash index 1 since 8 is less than or equal to 10
votes[7], 3 is hash index 5 since 2 is less than or equal to 3
votes[8], 2 is hash index 5 since 2 is less than or equal to 2
votes[9], 2 is hash index 5 since 2 is less than or equal to 2
```

This should gives [5, 1, 5, 10, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5].

I tried the following but the result is not what I expected.

```
results = []
votes.each{ |ele| popu_cost.each{ |key, val| 
  if l <= val
  results << key
  end
}}
results
```

Comment: Oh dear another down-vote. Thank you for that. Any reasons for down-vote?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll find insights here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252049

Comment: The result should be `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` since you are checking for keys where `votes element <= hash value`. As all votes are less than the first value, the answer should be one for all of the votes

Comment: shin, I gave my interpretation of your question in my answer.  If it is correct, feel free to edit your your question and use what I have written, modified as you wish.  If you want to do that, I suggest you remove the line "Now I want use..." and all lines beginning `votes[...`.  I will then remove the text you use from my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your code slightly.  First, however, the question needs to be clarified.  My understanding (corrrect me if I am wrong) is that, for each element `e` of `votes`, you want to find the first element `k=>v` of `popu_cost` for which `e >= v`, and (if one is found) add the key `k` to the array `result`.  For example, the first element of `votes` is 2.  The first element `k=>v` for which `2 >= v` is `5=>2`, so `result << 5`.

Note we must assume this is for Ruby 1.9+, as we are depending on the hash to maintain its insertion order.

Here is a modification of your code that creates the desired array:

```
popu_cost = {1=>8, 2=>8, 3=>7, 4=>5, 5=>2, 6=>5, 7=>2, 8=>7, 9=>2, 10=>1}
votes = [2, 8, 4, 1, 8, 2, 10, 3, 2, 2, 0]

results = []
votes.each do |e|
  key, _ = popu_cost.find { |_, val| e >= val }
  results << key if key
end  
results
  #=> [5, 1, 5, 10, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5]
```

Note that I've used `find` where you had `each`.  That was your main problem.  You don't want to find all the hash elements that meet the condition for each element of `votes`, just the first one.

Notice that I added a zero to the example you gave for `votes`.  That was to show that when there is no element `k=>v` of the hash for which `e >= v`, no key is added to `result`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this using [`.map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`.find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find), where `.map` applies a transformation to each input element and outputs a list with the result of each transformation, and `.find` can be used to find the first element of an `Enumerable` which yields `true` for a given block.

I use those to do the comparison you specified, and [`.first`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-first) will return only the `key` of the Hash, which is what you were interested in. The `-> {[]}` part specifies a lambda yielding an empty Array in case nothing was found, so the `.first` will then yield `nil`. This can happen when your `votes` contains a value which is smaller than all elements of `popu_cost`.

```
results = votes.map do |vote|
  popu_cost.find(-> {[]}) { |_, cost| cost <= vote }.first
end

# [5, 1, 5, 10, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Alternatively, `popu_cost.find { |_, cost| cost <= vote }.compact.first`.

Comment: Actually, `find` returns an element or `nil`, so calling `compact` on `nil` is no good. An alternative is actually `(.find { ... } || [] ).first`. In case you want to return nil when nothing matches, which I thought was nice. To always yield a same length result as the votes input

Comment: Yes, of course.  I expect I mixed that up with `votes.map { |vote| popu_cost.find { |_, cost| cost <= vote } }.compact.map(&:first)`, which is less efficient than what you have.  I prefer the alternative you just mentioned. (I must remember: always test!)

Comment: What is _ in |_, cost|?

Comment: @shin It is the key of the `popu_cost` Hash (1,2,3,4 etc.), but because it is not used in the `find` condition I denote it by `_`. I could have also called it `key` or some other name. `_` is still a "normal" variable but it just makes it clear it is not used.